My notification doesnt work when the app was terminated or closed
can anyone help me in my project in flutter android app because my main problem was that the push notification and i use FCM because  i use firebase for the database that the problem is that the notifications dont work when the app was terminated or closed that i have to login to work the notification
here's the main code:
// main.dart

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'login_screen.dart';
import 'notification_service.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
final NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // Ensure Firebase is initialized in the background

  notificationService.showNotification(
    message.data['title'],
    message.data['body'],
  );
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Register background message handler
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  // Initialize local notifications
  initializeLocalNotifications();

  // Sign in for notifications in the main app lifecycle
  await _signInForNotifications();

  // Get FCM token and save to Firebase
  await _initializeFCMToken();

  runApp(const FireGuard());
}

class FireGuard extends StatelessWidget {
  const FireGuard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'FireGuard Fire Safety',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> _signInForNotifications() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: "",
      password: "",
    );
    print("Signed in for notifications.");
  } catch (e) {
    print("Failed to sign in for notifications: $e");
  }
}

Future<void> _initializeFCMToken() async {
  // Request permissions for notifications on iOS
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  await messaging.requestPermission();

  // Get the FCM token
  String? token = await messaging.getToken();
  if (token != null) {
    await _saveTokenToNotificationNode(token);
  }

  // Listen for token refreshes and save new token if it changes
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen(_saveTokenToNotificationNode);
}

Future<void> _saveTokenToNotificationNode(String token) async {
  final DatabaseReference notificationRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("notifications");

  // Save the FCM token directly as the key in the notifications node
  await notificationRef.child(token).set({
    "FCMToken": token,
    "isActive": true, // Optional field to indicate the token's status
  });

  print("Token saved to notifications node in Firebase with token $token");
}

void initializeLocalNotifications() async {
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
}

here's the notification service code:
// notification_service.dart

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';
import 'main.dart'; // Import for flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin

class NotificationService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  NotificationService() {
    _initializeFCM();
  }

  // Initialize FCM
  void _initializeFCM() async {
    // Request notification permissions and subscribe to topics
    NotificationSettings settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');

    await _messaging.subscribeToTopic('fire_alerts');

    // FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    //   if (message.notification != null) {
    //      showNotification(
    //       message.data['title'] ?? 'Notification',
    //       message.data['body'] ?? 'You have a new message.',
    //     );
    //   }
    // });

        // Handle background messages
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        // _handleNotificationClick(message.data);
       showNotification(
          message.data['title'] ?? 'Notification',
          message.data['body'] ?? 'You have a new message.',
        );
    });


  }

  // Public method to display any notification
  void showNotification(String title, String body, {bool vibrate = false}) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your_channel_id',
      'Your Channel Name',
      channelDescription: 'Your Channel Description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      showWhen: true,
    );

    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      title,
      body,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    // Optionally trigger vibration if supported
    if (vibrate && (await Vibration.hasVibrator() ?? false)) {
      Vibration.vibrate(duration: 500); // 500 ms vibration
    }
  }

  // Save the FCM token (customize if needed for Firebase)
  Future<void> _saveTokenToFirebase(String token) async {
    print("FCM Token saved: $token");
  }

  // Public method to send a system notification
  void sendSystemNotification(String title, String body, {bool vibrate = true}) {
    showNotification(title, body, vibrate: vibrate);
  }
}

here's the code for the Notification:
import 'package:fireguard/notification_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';

import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';

class DashboardNotification extends StatefulWidget {
  final String username;

  const DashboardNotification({super.key, required this.username});

  @override
  _DashboardNotificationState createState() => _DashboardNotificationState();
}

class _DashboardNotificationState extends State<DashboardNotification> {
  String? macAddress;
  DateTime? loginTime;
  final DatabaseReference _clientAccountsRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("Client Accounts");
  final DatabaseReference _devicesRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("devices");
  final NotificationService _notificationService = NotificationService();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _fireNotifications = [];
  final Map<String, String> _lastNotifiedTimestamp = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loginTime = DateTime.now();
    // _initializeFCM(); // Initialize FCM for notifications
    _loadUserDevicesAndFireHistory();
    //initializeNotifications();
  }

  Future<void> _saveLastNotifiedTimestamps() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> timestamps = _lastNotifiedTimestamp.entries
        .map((entry) => "${entry.key}:${entry.value}")
        .toList();
    await prefs.setStringList('lastNotifiedTimestamps', timestamps);
  }

    void _sendSystemNotification(String macAddress, String fireTimestamp, String severityLevel) {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final DateTime fireEventTime = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').parse(fireTimestamp);

    // Check if the fire event is after the login time to avoid old events triggering notifications
    if (fireEventTime.isAfter(loginTime!)) {
      final DateTime? lastNotified = _lastNotifiedTimestamp[macAddress] != null
          ? DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').parse(_lastNotifiedTimestamp[macAddress]!)
          : null;

      // Set a cooldown period (5 minutes)
      const int cooldownPeriodInSeconds = 300;

      if (lastNotified == null || now.difference(lastNotified).inSeconds > cooldownPeriodInSeconds) {
        // Use NotificationService to send the notification with vibration
        _notificationService.sendSystemNotification(
          'Fire Detected! - Severity Level: $severityLevel',
          'Fire detected in device: $macAddress at $fireTimestamp ',
          vibrate: true,
        );

        // Update the last notified timestamp for the device
        _lastNotifiedTimestamp[macAddress] = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').format(now);

        // Save the last notified timestamps to shared preferences
        _saveLastNotifiedTimestamps();
      } else {
        print('Notification suppressed to prevent duplicates (Cooldown in effect)');
      }
    } else {
      print('Notification suppressed as fire event occurred before login.');
    }
  }

i tried to see on youtube, documentation but still doesnt work my main issue

Hey dude !
We are experencing the same problem with android (also iOS) since few weeks now after upgrading all our stuff so we are currently working on it. We are doing almost the same stuff as your are so I hope someone will have any idea how to help cause it's kinda a problem.

@NicolasLeBot did you already fix it?
